# VS Code Scipy/Scikit-Learn installation metadata error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn, metadata

I'm using VS Code on a 2018 Lenovo P51 with Windows 10 and a 32 GB ram.
I'm trying to install the SKLearn module in Python.
I've written pip install scikit-learn --verbose in the terminal to do so. It's able to install the build dependencies, the build wheel, and the backend dependencies. But when it gets to the preparing metadata stage, I get an error saying that preparing metadata(pyproject.toml) did not run successfully. How can I fix this error so that I can install SKLearn?

Answer (score 0):

You were hoping `pip` would find a binary wheel,
and it didn't work out for your platform.

I usually install via
[conda](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/miniconda),
for a smoother binary install experience.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this similar issue in github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/24749), I found a possible solution.

You could try to set the environment variable:

```
SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib
```